# Taking the address of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

If I declare the following variables:

```
int array[10] = { 34, 43,12, 67, 34, 43,26, 98, 423,1 };
int * p = array;
```

Then, this loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    std::cout << &*p++ << " ";
}
```

gives me different output ( a different set of addresses ), to this code:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    std::cout << p++ << " ";
}
```

Why? Aren't they semantically equivalent?

EDIT:

Well, my apologies to everyone that answered this one, I don't have the original code, it was a test that I did at home and it turns out that I deleted that code from my project. ( my broadband is not yet connected, so I waited till I got to work to post this ). Anyway - I am pretty sure that I was forgetting to initialise `p`. But the question of "aren't they semantically equivalent?" has been answered. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is related to the precedence of operators. What happens if you add parenthesis ?

Comment: Post some output as well and the exact code. I think you will need to reinitialize `p` as a poster explained.

Comment: @dirkgently - its possible - my original code is at home. oh no - I might have posted a duff question here. uh - oh.

Comment: @BeeBand Don't worry about it - we all do it all the time. Myself more than anyone else it seems. Every time I come across a problem that I don't understand, I spend ages trying to work it out, then post it here and the first answer is something like "You've forgotten to return anything from that function." XD.

Comment: @BeeBand: Nevertheless, it's prompted an interesting discussion below!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Not sure I'd call it interesting, to be honest. Cedric is just... well, he's incorrect and people are trying to explain it. And (at time of posting) we are so far failing at doing so.

Comment: Thanks for understanding guys! I am sometimes a bit trigger happy when it comes to posting questions. Anyway, I'll grab the code tonight and post it. It probably is that I failed to reinit `p`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int array[10] = { 34, 43,12, 67, 34, 43,26, 98, 423,1 };
int * p = array;

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    std::cout << p++ << " ";
}
p = array;
std::cout << '\n';
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    std::cout << &*p++ << " ";
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Gives me the same addresses. Did you accidentally forget `p = array;` in between?

Answer (score 4):

If you remember to reset `p` before the second loop, they give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

reset the pointer p's position.

Answer (score -1):

The order of precedence is '++' first, then '*' and finally '&'.

So `p++` will output the adresse of `array[0]` and `&*p++` will first increment p, but this is postfix ! So the value of p (and not the value of p+1) will be given to * and then to &, so these are the same

Example:

```
std::cout << p << std::endl; // Output the adress of p
std::cout << &*p++<<std::endl; // p is increment but it is postfix, so value of p is used and printed
std::cout << &*++p<<std::endl; // p has been increment before and is then incremented again
std::cout << p++ << std::endl; // p has been incremented before, but here p is used first, then incremented
```

Comment: -1: Precedence determines binding of operators, not order of evaluation.  The postfix `++` always gets evaluated last, so `&*p++` should be equivalent to `&*p` followed by `p++`.

Comment: I think `++` will be evaluated first.

Comment: No, it isn't.  That's the whole point of having prefix and postfix unary operators!

Comment: @Cedric H. Even though ++ has higher precedence, p++ and &*p++ won't give different results because ++ is postfix and so will return the pointer's value before the change, and that previous value will be fed to * . cout << p++ prints the same as cout << p which prints the same as &*p++ .

Comment: It is evaluated first, but because it is postix, its value before incrementation is used (by * and then by &).

Comment: @Cedric H.: &, * and ++ have same precedence. So it will be evaluated in the order of their appearance in the expression

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Actually postfix ++ evaluates first here, but the old value is used for dereference, not the new value that increment produced.

Comment: @Chubsdad: that's not what http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence says.

Comment: I corrected my post to make it more clear ... What about the example ? I think the reasoning is correct.

Comment: @Cedric: Your post is now correct, but now doesn't address the question!

Comment: @usta: I don't believe the order of precise evaluation is specified, because there isn't a sequence point.

Comment: @Cedruc H. You are still wrong. `&*++p` does not have the same meaning as `p++`. This is not a problem with post and prefixes, it is (or at least the only possible error I can see) a problem with him not resetting p. Your logic does not make sense.

Comment: @Cedric H. It's better now, but `&*++p` does not have the same result as `p++`, it has the same result as `++p`

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Technically yes, even though `*&p++` is equivalent to `&(*(p++))` according to precedences so the natural thing would be to evaluate ++ first, the compiler can do the increment to `p` after determining the address to use for cout. However that does not change the semantics, the value `p` had before it is incremented will always be printed, regardless if ++ is actually evaluated first  or not.

Comment: Okay guys, I read your arguments, I started with an idea in mind at the beginning which was not correct, then I understood your arguments but without correcting everything, resulting in a messy, incorrect post.